# Is it okay to point readers to the edit history of an answer for old, (mostly) out-of-date information?

Tags: discussion, answers, editing

*Background:* For the last year or so, new features for Windows Subsystem for Linux (currently my primary area of expertise here) have been limited to Windows 11.  With a recent release of WSL last week, those features are now available for Windows 10 users as well.

I've been working through editing a number of my old answers to keep them up-to-date.  Sometimes, as in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1667985/1210833), the new way of doing things is just so much better that I'd like to replace the old answer entirely.

The problem is that, likely for a short period of time, some users still won't be able to upgrade as corporate IT rolls out the Windows monthly servicing releases.  I have three options that I can see:

1. Add the "new way" and the "old way" in the same answer, just in case someone still needs the "old way" in the next few weeks.  I don't like this, as it makes the answer more convoluted.  I've done this in the past, and then someone comes along and just answers with the "new way" (because they didn't bother reading the "too long" version with *both*).  Almost inevitably, that answer then starts getting more upvotes than my "full version".  So it seems clear that users/voters prefer the concise, shorter form.
2. Add a new answer with the "new way", keep the old answer, and just put a warning and link at the top of the old that most users should see the new answer first.
3. What I've currently opted for in a couple of these cases, like the answer referenced above, where it seems unlikely that anyone will need the "old way", is to just replace the existing answer entirely with the "new way" and point readers to the Edit History (with a link directly to the old information) in the unlikely event they need it.

   This, to me, keeps the answer list "cleaner" while still providing the old information.

Does anyone see issues with this approach?  Would you prefer another approach from above?  I don't have strong feelings on using method #2 or #3, but I'd like to avoid #1 for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: The edit history does not always show the answer with the correct formatting so I would avoid this. I vote for option 2.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks - Was not aware of that.  I thought using the [link](https://superuser.com/revisions/1667985/2) to a particular revision keeps the formatting.  But good to hear that option #2 looks good to you as well.

Comment: Option #2 seems fine to me. In general there is a possibility the new way is wrong or flawed; adding to or replacing the old answer that may have received its own upvotes is a potential abuse. #2 works well also for answers from different users ([example](https://superuser.com/a/1067213/432690)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidPostill and @KamilMaciorowski for the feedback in the comments.

I've reverted from Option #3 to #2 based on their advice.  For the particular answer I mentioned above, I've:

- Rolled-back the original answer to the pre-update information.
- Created a [new answer](https://superuser.com/a/1754527/1210833) with the latest/update information
- Inserted an Update message at the top of the [old answer](https://superuser.com/a/1731418/1210833) that I believe it is outdated, and pointing readers to the latest information in my new answer.